# validate url without https:// http:// means also can accept if url is www accepts both (http and www)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regex using JavaScript for url that can accepts only 
with  https:// ( http://) or without  http like the url which starts with www.

like

```
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
www.google.com
```

Here is my regex

```
/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www\.)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)+\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/
```

but what wrong is here is that it some times accpet do not accept

```
www.abc.com
```

it accepts 
www.acbc
and

```
 http://www.google
 https://www.google
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor English... I am a little confused... like what does "with or with" in title and something like "sometimes accept do not accept" mean...

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This question has nothing to do with `jquery`, or (unless you're writing code for iOS, which the regex syntax you're using suggests you're not) `nsregularexpression`, or `regular-language` (if it applied here, it would apply to every `regex` question everywhere).

Comment: sorry @iplus26 kindly check the statement again mean regex can accept the url with out http ,https in short also accepts url whcih start with www.

Comment: Would you explain the purpose of the later part of the regular expression? `[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)+\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?`

Comment: @Churix after www. or http://www. their can by 0-9 or a-z character after that their can be . after . ther can com org in some charcters

Comment: According to [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/urls.html#url) and [RFC3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-A), the definition of an URL could be very broad. You have to be more precise on what you really need. Your question only ask for the urls begins with https or http or www, but never mention about what you need to check in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `((http|ftp|https)://)?([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})*(/[a-zA-Z0-9\&%_\./-~-]*)?`

**Update:**

If you want use it in JavaScript, it should be:

```js
var re = /((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})*(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\&%_\.\/-~-]*)?/;

console.log(re.test('http://www.google.com'));
console.log(re.test('https://www.google.com'));
console.log(re.test('www.google.com'));
console.log(re.test('google'));
```

The definition of url is very board, so I suppose that only the regular expression can't do all the jobs.

Comment: Same issue @iplus it accepts http://wwww.foo and http://wwwwdsddsdsds.foo and also www.goo tested on https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: @usama if you want xxxx.foo not accepted, I suppose that you have to list all '.com', '.cn', '.org'... which is impossible... and neither should you refuse url like 'photos.google.com' if it's not necessary?

Comment: i am using your regex like this /((http|ftp|https)://)?([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})*(/[a-zA-Z0-9\&%_\./-~-]*)?/,
but it is giving me this error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: @usama you should add '\' before '/' when you use it in JavaScript. It's my fault that I just post the normal regular expression here.